# (re) mount usb device

Tags: usb, mount

I just can't seem to figure out the exact mount-command to re-mount my phone. It used to automatically appear, but for some reason in stopped. I need help to get the mount-statement right.

The device is listed in lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1058:1100 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 4971:1014 SimpleTech 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04e8:685c Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

And dmesg nicely tells about the device getting connected:

```
[ 8469.512061] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[ 8469.645304] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=685c
[ 8469.645310] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 8469.645315] usb 2-2: Product: Galaxy Nexus
[ 8469.645318] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: samsung
[ 8469.645321] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 0146A5B31900D012
```

How do i glue this together to a working mount-command?

Comment: in /, under `Media` is anything available?

Comment: Look at the files in `/dev` - run `ls /dev`. Then plug in your phone, and wait a few seconds. Run `ls /dev` again, and anything new should be the device name for you phone (usually `/dev/sdb` or  `/dev/sdc` ). Then use that to run `mount DEVICE-NAME /PATH/TO/WHERE/YOU/WANT/TO/MOUNT/IT`. Being a Samsung phone (though a Nexus), have you changed any of the 'mass storage' settings?

Comment: type `sudo fdisk -l` in a terminal and post the output. (post it in the question itself; hit the "edit" button.

Comment: @Projjol - nope, nothing

Comment: @wilf the only folder that changes is a folder 'libmtp-2-2', no changes in /sd* -folders

Comment: @MinaMichael the device does not show up in fdisk.

Comment: The `[libmtp](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/)` is relates to the media transfer protocol, so that also show whether it is connecting - if it shows up in `/dev` it should show up in `fdisk` as well. Try searching for and installing anything useful related to `mtp`, `phone` or whatever in `apt-cache` or software centre, then it might work - I had to something similar for my phone to connect. You can also run `mtp-detect`, which will show up mtp connections - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134727. If you find the /dev file, running `mount /dev/? /PATH/TO/EMPTY/DIRECTORY`

Comment: Does [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1408843) help?

Comment: @wilf thanks for the help so far! i'll look into it this weekend.

Comment: are you sure? can I please see the output? and by the way you should wait until the "dollar sign" appears again (user@host:~$). It can take up to five minutes!

Comment: @MinaMichael - if it'll show in `fdisk`, it'll be in `/dev` - that is where the device files are, and was eventaully how I managed to get my phone connecting.

Comment: yes you're right. so did you manage to mount it? :D

Comment: well, i installed `mtpfs` and i can mount the phone using `mtpfs /path/to/mount`. But when i go to the folder, it only shows some default shared-folders, not the full list of folders i expect to see. Can i do anything else with `mtpfs`?

Comment: ...well I know how to give you a normal mount command if you'd give me the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 0):

**Figure out its uuid:**

(At least once, under whatever circumstances, if nothing helps, by mounting it on a friends machine). First, let's get the current id. (that can change again, on another time)

```
mount | grep ^/dev
```

You should somewhere should recognize its actual name here,

```
/dev/sda4...
/dev/sda5 on /boot ...
/dev/sdc1 on /media/frank/iPhoneWhatsoever...
/dev/sdc2 on /media/frank/my BackupDrive...
```

Now, say, it's sdb1. Let's figure out its truly unique uuid:

```
$> ll /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sdc1
```

Should get you a fairly long string (often hex, sometimes with dashes)

```
lrwxrwxrwx [...]  366A2F886A2F003A -> ../../sdc1
```

**manual mount**

*directory must pre-exist, not taken care of. so generate it (only once, ever):*

```
sudo mkdir /media/myFx
```

And here we go

```
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/366A2F886A2F003A /media/myFX
```

**manual unmount**

```
sudo umount /dev/disk/by-uuid/366A2F886A2F003A
```

Additionally if not done yet, add it to `/etc/fstab`.
For that or for mount command (see man pages) you might want to use additional parameters, if there are problems with your preferred user rights, a ‘rare’ drive format etc... Just as a sketch:

sudo mount -t ntfs -o umask=007,gid=046,uid=0,nls=utf8 /dev/disk/by-uuid/366A2F886A2F003A /media/myFX