# Not able to see Galaxy A5 device as mounted - MTP fail?

Tags: usb, mount, mtp

My Galaxy A5 (2017) is not mounting automatically although it appears to be recognized properly (see dmesg) and it is set for MTP transfer:

```
[ 1799.793224] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1813.883366] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1814.011999] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[ 1814.012004] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1814.012007] usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[ 1814.012009] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[ 1814.012011] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 5210e432c0641479
[ 1814.013521] cdc_acm 3-1:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Furthermore `lsusb` clearly lists my phone:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
```

In addition, my phone keeps flashing an error message:

```
Attention
The connected device is unable to access data on this device. 
Reconnect the USB cable and try again.
```

I am using a Type-C cable on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS running on an ASUS laptop.

I saw the question and answer at [(re) mount usb device](https://askubuntu.com/q/383502/176221), yet it doesn't work for me since `mount | grep ^/dev` shows nothing related to my phone. That being said, I do see `/dev/ttyACM0`, yet `mount` failed with the error message:

```
mount:  /dev/ttyACM0 is not a block device
```

--EDIT 1--

I didn't get any better results in PTP mode - i.e. the phone was not automatically mounted:

```
[ 3517.875378] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 3517.876961] cdc_acm 3-1:1.1: failed to set dtr/rts
[ 3518.183436] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 3518.312069] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6866
[ 3518.312077] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3518.312082] usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[ 3518.312085] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[ 3518.312088] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 5210e432c0641479
```

--EDIT2--

Running `gmtp` shows the following:

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:1
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Detect: No available Storage found on device?
```

--EDIT3--

The same cable, connected to the same USB port, on the same (dual boot) computer, mounts the device just fine in Win10

Comment: Does it work in PTP mode?

Comment: That's weird. Make sure to enable MTP or PTP mode. The phone should ask you whether you want charge only or share files.

Comment: edited above...

Comment: A possible solution would be to unlock developer options on your phone and enable `USB debugging` option under debugging section. Should allow data transfer between the devices

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @user633551; this is already the case for my phone (I use it for app development)

Comment: Hmm, it could be either cable issues or power settings on your pc. Check this thread for more information...https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6-edge/565970-my-galaxy-s6-edge-keeps-connecting-disconnecting-my-pc-already-reinstalled-drivers-windows-10-a.html

Comment: It's not a cable issue. The cable works properly on my home PC